# Echo not displaying. PHP

Tags: php

I have an echo after each header redirect. But it does not pop up. So when the user enters an invalid login detail no message pops up. What am I doing wrong?
I tried a JavaScript method as well but did not manage to fix the issue.
Is it something to do with my nested ifs maybe?

```
<?php

session_start();

#first if
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include 'dbh.inc.php';

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['uid'] );
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['pwd'] );

    //Error handlers
    //Check if this input are empty
    #second if
    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    }/*second else*/ else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        #third if
        if ($resultCheck < 1) {

            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            echo "Login error";
            exit();
        }/*third else*/ else {
            #forth if
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                //de-hashing the password
                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd , $row['user_pwd']);
                #fifth if
                if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {

                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                    echo "Login error";


                    exit();
                } /*fifth else*/ elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                    //Log in the user here
                    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                    $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                    $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                    $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
                    $uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                    echo "Login error";
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}/*first else*/ else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    echo "Login error";
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: Redirect (303) header does not contain a body, while a success (200) header does.

Comment: I tried to do it. But it did not work either. I am not sure whats causing this.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. When you redirect, you're telling the browser to go to that other page immediately, without showing anything from the current page.

Comment: `header` sends the user to another page (when `location` is used) so they aren't on the page when it renders. You should append the message you want as a GET parameter on the redirect, then use that on the next page to display.

Comment: If you want to show a message temporarily before redirecting, you could send a `Refresh` header instead, with a delay period. See http://www.otsukare.info/2015/03/26/refresh-http-header for examples

Answer (score 0):

If you use `location` headers you can never display messages - the browser ignores the rest of the request and does the redirect immediately, because the HTTP code is changed to 302.

Even if you could show a message, it would not be a good experience for the user, as it would only display for a fraction of a second and then the redirect would happen and the page would be overwritten. You should show the error message on the landing page (index.php?login=error).